# Issue with child components inside lightning-tabset

Tags: lightning-web-components

Playground link: https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/igxyxtS3TKauBJEnQFlV

Error message: `Uncaught TypeError: tab.loadContent is not a function`

parent.html

```
<template>
    
    <lightning-tabset>
        <c-child></c-child>
    </lightning-tabset>

</template>
```

child.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-tab></lightning-tab>
</template>
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. It works fine if I have the `lightning-tab` element at the parent level, but my use case involves setting the `label` for this element dynamically, which is only possible in a child component.

Is there something simple I'm not seeing here?

Comment: Do you want dynamic label for the lightning-tab?

Comment: Yep, based on a child's data.

Comment: I think this is a [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You may want to explain your actual problem a bit better. What do you exactly need? Why won't it work when the tab is in parent?. I think the errors you're getting are expected since `lightning-tabset` no longer owns `lightnint-tab` because  they're now part of another component & prevent via `shadow dom`.

Comment: @SachinHooda `lightning-tab` needs to be part of my child's component, since I need to set the `label` for the `lightning-tab` element dynamically. Dynamically means this label is different for each child and there's some logic behind it, i.e. I need to use a getter. 

I guess it makes sense that `lightning-tabset` no longer owns `lightning-tab`. In that case I only see one last resort, which is creating a separate field which is supposed to be the JS getter, having `lightning-tab` on the parent level and filling in the `label` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sfdcfox mentioned, all lightning component blocks that require nesting (e.g. `lightning-tabset`) can't read out a child's content and as such, it's impossible to have `lightning-tab` as part of the child's component.

I eventually solved it by computing the label's value in my wired function.
For example:

```
    lots;

    @wire(getLots, {caseId: '$recordId'})
    wiredLots({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.lots = data.map((lot) => ({
                ...lot,
                Label : lot.hasOwnProperty('Product__c') ? lot.Product__c : lot.Name
            }));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the elements with nested custom components (e.g. lightning-path, lightning-accordion, lightning-tabset, ...) all suffer from this as a limitation. It happens because the content inside a component is not accessible to components outside of it. A workaround is to notify the parent of the desired label:

```
<lightning-tabset>
  <lightning-tab>
    <c-my-component ontablabelchange={handleTabLabelChange}>
    </c-my-component>
  </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
```

---

```
handleTabLabelChange(event) {
  event.target.closest('lightning-tab').label = event.detail.label
}
```

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-button label="Update Label" onclick={handleLabelUpdateButtonClick}>
  </lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

```
  handleLabelUpdateButtonClick() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent(
        'tablabelchange',
        { detail: { label: 'Hello World' }}
      )
    )
  }
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/wavMqGJIrhWFh4Y83TPs/src/myComponent.js?p=stories).

This is only illustrative. You can use renderedCallback(), connectedCallback(), etc to react initially if you want to. You just need to fire off the event when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution and the clarification about the limitiation :). However, this doesn't work for me as I need the label values when the parent (tabset) component is first inserted. Tab values are, logically speaking, part of the tabset component. In your solution, I end up with a set of empty tabs, up until I click on them, which would, only then, trigger the child's connectedCallback method. 

I eventually solved it by wiring my data to a function and computing the label value there.